Change order/calculation in numerator of Bayes' theorem?
I have a question regarding Bayes' theorem.
Bayes theorem is given as:
$$P(H \vert E) = \frac{P(E \vert H) P(H)}{P(E)}.$$
Given the information that $P(E \vert H) P(H) = P( H \cap E) =  P( E \cap H) = P(H \vert E) P(E) $, we should be able to rewrite Bayes' theorem as:
$$P(H \vert E) = \frac{P(H \vert E) P(E)}{P(E)}.$$
Am I correct in my thinking? I know that this is not particularly useful, since then we already know the information we are looking for. However, some online tools said that the equality does not hold; so I just wanted to check whether I am on some wrong path and if yes why.
Thanks!

Barring cases in which one or more of those terms is $0$, all this says is that $1=1$.

Do you mean $P(E|H)=\dfrac{P(H|E)P(E)}{P(H)}$.

@AngaeMT, no np; i do mean just changing the numerator of the righthand side based on the equality I mentioned in the middle of my post.

@Aaron But if thats the case then the $P(E)$ on nunmerator and denominator can cancel out, and you get $A=A$.

@lulu I know that it basically only says that, but I am confused as to how such an obvious and mathematically correct equality transformation turns everything weird and... not useful anymore... maybe it is more a problem of understanding with the underlying mathematical "philosophy"... or idk...

The original formula doesn't say much in the first place...it is basically the definition of conditional probability.

@AngaeMT yeah I know! I mean in a way it makes sense, since we are learning nothing new because the answer is already on the righthand side! I basically just wanted to check whether my reasoning and re-formulation is correct?

Your reasoning  that  from A=A  deduce, that$A=\frac{A*B}{B}$ is ok and useless.   If you say "However, some online tools said that the equality does not hold" I would not use this online tool!

You've started with Bayes' Theorem and ended with something that basically says $x=x$. If you just reverse your steps, however, you've got something interesting because then you've figured out a derivation of Bayes' Theorem (you're allowed to start with $x=x$ in your derivation, because that's known to be true).

@ZoeAllen I like that take! Thanks!

@trula Yeah you are right haha :)

Because $P(E \cap H) ={P(E|H).P(H)} = {P(H|E).P(E)}$,
if we know $P(E|H)$, and need to find out $P(H|E)$,
we use Bayes' Theorem to invert the conditional probability
What you have written, after cancelling out like terms in the numerator and denominator of the right hand side, just reduces to $P(H|E) = P(H|E)$ which, while true,  takes us nowhere !
